# Trying to summarize a database using SUMIFS - VBA

Tags: vba, sumifs

'The number rows in the database changes each month hence the variable lastCode.
'The code runs without problems when I manually put last row in i.e. `$M$22510` and `$O$22510` however when I put the variable `& lastCode` in the `SUMIFS` I  receive the error

> Run-time '1004'application-defined or object defined.

Please tell me what is wrong with my `SUMIFS` in the code below.

```
Sub SumGroups()
    Worksheets("Database").Activate
    Dim lastCode, lastFiltCode As Integer
    Dim Formula As String
    'Determine Last Row in Column O (Unfiltered Codes)
    lastCode = Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'Filter Unique Codes into Column A Sheet2
    Range("O1:O" & lastCode).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=Sheet2.Range("A1"), Unique:=True
    'Determine last Row in Column A (Filtered Codes)
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    lastFiltCode = Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Place SUMIF Formula in Column B Sheet2

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B" & lastFiltCode).Formula = _
        "=SUMIFS(Database!$M$2:$M$ & lastCode,Database!$O$2:$O$ & lastCode,A2)"
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to concatenate the formula in VBA - `lastCode` doesn't mean anything in the formula itself:  `"=SUMIFS(Database!$M$2:$M$" & lastCode & ",Database!$O$2:$O$" & lastCode & ",A2)"`

Comment: Thank you! That works. Comintern you are a scholar and a gentleman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is:

`"=SUMIFS(Database!$M$2:$M$" & lastCode & ",Database!$O$2:$O$" & lastCode & ",A2)"`

The reason for this is when you put something into "quotation marks" VBA will read it as just text, you can use `Debug.Print "=SUMIFS(Database!$M$2:$M$ & lastCode,Database!$O$2:$O$ & lastCode,A2)"` and either press Ctrl + G or in VBA select "View" > "Immidiate Window" and it will show you what exactly is going into Excel

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Mr.Burns